# quicksort and insertion sort hybrid expected running time

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, quicksort, insertion-sort, clrs

I am self learning CLRS 3rd edition and here is one of the tougher questions that I have encountered **along with its answer** as a service to all.

**7.4-5**
We can improve the running time of quicksort in practice by taking advantage of the
fast running time of insertion sort when its input is “nearly” sorted. Upon calling
quicksort on a subarray with fewer than `k` elements, let it simply return without
sorting the subarray. After the top-level call to quicksort returns, run insertion sort
on the entire array to ﬁnish the sorting process. Argue that this sorting algorithm
runs in `O(nk+nlg(n/k))` expected time. How should we pick `k`, both in theory
and in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you eval equation `nlgn > nk + nlog(n/k)` you get `log k > k`. Which is impossible. Hence in theory it's not possible. But in practice there are constant factors involved with insertion sort and quicksort. Take a look at the solution discussed in this [pdf](http://s3.alirezaweb.com/91-5/introduction-to-algorithms/solution-manual/CLRS-Exercises-Introduction-to-Algorithms_Borna66/CLRS-Introduction-to-Algorithms/H6-solution%5Bwww.alirezaweb.com%5D.pdf). You might want to update your answer. .

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer is `k = 8`.

The algorithm you get is the composition of two anonymous functions, one of which is `O(nk)` and the other which is `O(n lg n/k)`.  Those anonymous functions hide average case constants.  Insertion sort runs in `n^2/4` time in the average case and randomized quicksort runs in `1.386 n lg n` in the average case.  We want to find a value of `k` which minimizes the value of `nk/4 + 1.386( n lg n/k )` which equals `nk/4 + 1.386 n lg n - 1.386 n lg k`.  This means finding the maximum of the function `1.386 lg k - k/4`.  That maximum value occurs at `k = 8`.

Answer (score 0):

A leaf has an equal probability to be of size between `1` to `k`.
So the expected size of a leaf is `k/2`.
If the expected size of a leaf is `k/2` then we expect `n/(k/2)=(2n)/k` such leaves.
For simplicity lets say that we expect `n/k` such leaves and that the expected size of each leaf is `k`.
The expected running time of `INSERTION-SORT` is `O(n^2)`.
We found that in exercise 5.2-5 and problem 2-4c.
So the expected running time of `INSERTION-SORT` usage is `O((n/k)*(k^2))=O(nk)`.
If we expect our partition groups to be of size `k` then the height of the recursion tree is expected to be `lgn-lgk=lg(n/k)` since we expect to stop `lgk` earlier.
There are `O(n)` operations on each level of the recursion tree.
That leads us to `O(nlg(n/k))`.
We conclude that the expected running time is `O(nk+nlg(n/k))`.

In theory, we should pick `k=lgn`, since this way we get the best expected running time of `O(nlgn)`.

In practice, we should pick `k` to one of the values around `lgn` that gives us better performance than just running `RANDOMIZED-QUICKSORT`.

The second part of the answer uses big-O notation quite loosely, so for a more precise picking of `k`, please follow the link given in the second answer by Ankush.

Comment: Your answer is slightly wrong.  The best you can say in theory is that k must be some function such that k=O(lg n). To precisely pick k you have to look at the average case constants involved in insertion sort and quicksort.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and you are right. When I first posted the question and its answer, I was more interested in the first part of the question and in some sense skipped the second part of it.

Comment: Are you also studying in OpenU?  We had this question on our Maman this semester.

Comment: I graduated a long time ago, I learn this book at my free time.